# Loops and pulling lines of data from multiple dates

Tags: vba, loops, nested-loops

And thanks in advance for any help you can provide. I'm fairly new to VBA and this is outside of my current capability.

Ok, so I have raw data that is broken up by date and time in 30 minute intervals (Columns A, B). I have built a loop to find a specific segment (lines of data using Start Time, and Stop Time). What I am having issues with is pulling a timeframe for multiple days. The code is pulling the entire segment from start to end time, regardless of the date. So I end up with a large chunk of data that needs to be trimmed down.

Here is the code I'm using currently. 
Key: *A2 = Start Date, *B2 = Start Time, *C2 = End Date, *D2 = End Time.

```
'============================================
'    Date/Time lookup in Adjusted Table
'============================================

Sheets("Allotments (ADJ)").Select
i = 1
Do Until Cells(i, 1) = ""

If Cells(i, 1) = Sheets("macros").Range("a2") Then
  Do Until Cells(i, 1) <> Sheets("macros").Range("a2")
    If Cells(i, 2) = Sheets("macros").Range("b2") Then
        startrow = i
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Loop
End If
i = i + 1
Loop

i = 1
Do Until Cells(i, 1) = ""
If Cells(i, 1) = Sheets("macros").Range("c2") Then
   Do Until Cells(i, 1) <> Sheets("macros").Range("c2")
      If Cells(i, 2) = Sheets("macros").Range("d2") Then
        endrow = i
      End If
      i = i + 1
   Loop
End If
i = i + 1
Loop

Sheets("Allotments (ADJ)").Range("a" & startrow & ":l" & endrow).Copy
Sheets("macros").Select
Range("c3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
CutCopyMode = False
```

Is there a way I can modify this to grab only a desgnated timeframe for each day, if I'm trying to pull from multiple date range?

Comment: an idea might be to use an input box to set the date range you want to pull.  So you click run a box opens up you enter in start data then enter then end date then enter and use those variables as what your macro looks for.

Comment: That's exactly what I have. When I run the macro it grabs data from the start date and time all the way to the end date and time. So if for example I were to have the start date/time as 6/10/2014 08:30 and the end date/time of 6/12/2014 11:30, it returns 102 rows of data. I would only need 08:30 through 11:30 for 6/10, 6/11, and 6/12 which should only return 21 rows of data. If that makes sense.

Comment: I finally figured it out

Answer (score 1):

After tinkering with it for a long time and making the variables clearer I was able to get a working version.

StartDate = DateValue(StartDate)
EndDate = DateValue(EndDate)

Sheets("Allotments (ADJ)").Select

```
If StartDate = EndDate Then

    datestart = 2
    Do Until Range("A" & datestart) = ""
        If Sheets("Allotments (ADJ)").Range("A" & datestart).Value = StartDate Then

             StartTimerow = datestart
             Do Until Range("B" & StartTimerow).Value = StartTime
                 StartTimerow = StartTimerow + 1
             Loop

              Endtimerow = StartTimerow
              Do Until Range("B" & Endtimerow).Value = EndTime
                Endtimerow = Endtimerow + 1
              Loop

             Exit Do
         End If
        datestart = datestart + 1

     Loop

 Sheets("Allotments (ADJ)").Range("a" & StartTimerow & ":N" & Endtimerow).Copy
 Sheets("Macros").Select
 Range("C1").Select
 Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```